# iOS camera permission dialog box

Tags: ios, xcode, camera

I am working on an app for ios and my app uses the camera permission. However the dialog box for the camera permission shows behind the application. This gives the user the impression that the app has frozen. The user then has to press the home button and click Allow then go back to the app.

What can i check to ensure the camera dialog is always on top of the application?

Comment: Super strange bug. Can you post your code where you ask permissions for the camera, please.

Comment: Can you provide screenshot or code ?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have access to the code currently was just thinking about the problem. Is there anything I can check, i am curious what handles the permission pop up. Is it a setting in requirements or would it be in code?